# How to change or update the theme of angular ag-grid . Do we need to write any custom CSS files or use any other grid except from material

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a service file which is calling the API and getting the data.
I am showing the received data to the ag-grid by assigning the row data value to component variable value. Also I am using ag-grid  theme and display the data in rows. Which is successful happening now, but when If I want to change at-grid style like not show any  grind borders, each row text color, grid backgrounds color etc  you make it look like a designed wire frame, am unable to do it with the less knowledge on angular Not sure what is best way to achieve it. Wondering if any of you can help me?

Also one more question is, I have data with w,x,y columns coming from the api , how to add the column z which is not in api  and add valises to rows

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can overide variables in ag-grid theme. The list of variables is here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-provided/#customizing-sass-variables

The other styles you can override just like normal css styles overrides.

About your second question:
You did not tell us which (if any) framework you're using, so I'm going to tell my experience with angular ag-grid.

When I need to add column z in to the datatset I map the observable result from the api like this:

```
this.apiService.getData().pipe(
  map((results: Array<any>) => results.map(item => item['z'] = valueZ))
).subscribe(results => this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(results));
```